# Restricting advanced search in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to restrict the advanced search like enable the user to search only on four conditions or lesser than that.

Comment: Technically one can implement almost any requirements, but I don't understand why it could be good to implement such restriction. The more searching criteria the user know the more exactly he can specify the data which he need to see. If you would use HTTP POST you will have no restrictions in the length of the request.

Comment: Oleg Thanks for your comment, as I am doing server side search I need to restrict the user on search conditions. So how it can be done, any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement the requirement is to disable/enable "Add" button of the searching dialog based on the number of rules. You can make the changes inside of [afterRedraw](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) callback. If you have the requirement as common requirement for all grids you can set `afterRedraw` callback in `$.jgrid.search`. The code can looks like the following:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    recreateFilter: true,
    multipleSearch: true,
    multipleGroup: true, // remove the setting if you don't need grouping
    afterRedraw: function () {
        var needBeDisabled = $(this).find(".columns").length >= 4;
        $(this).find(".add-rule,.add-group").each(function() {
            $(this).prop("disabled", needBeDisabled);
        });
    }
});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RestrictNumberOfSearchingRules.htm) where I restricted the number of rules to maximal two:

[image]