# Limit adding search options in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I was working on jqgrid functionality. In multi searching in jqgrid, on clicking '+' button continuously, the number of search tabs will be added infinitely. Is there any way to limit the adding of search rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `afterRedraw` callback to calculate the number of rules and to disable '+' buttons after the limit is archived. If the number of buttons less then the limit one should enable '+' buttons. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13306443/315935) for more details.