# While zooming out horizontal scroll bar appears in subgtid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a one subgrid for every row which contains 5 columns. When I set zoom to 100% in IE grid looks good. But if I zoom it out to 75%, horizontal scroll bar totally hides the subgrid. I tried manybpossible ways. Didnt work.Please anyone help me out.

Comment: @Oleg. Please have a look at this.

Comment: Could you try whether the problem is exist if you use jqGrid from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (just replace `grid.locale-XX.js`, and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`/`jquery.jqGrid.min.js`)? Could you post small demo which can be used to reproduce the problem? Which version of web browser you use? Is IE8 is still important for you? Which version of jqGrid you use currently? There are some ways to solve the problem. The simplest one consist from calling of `setGridWidth` inside of `$(window).resize` event handler. The details I can post after you answer on the above questions?

Comment: Hi @Oleg. Sorry for the late reply. I changed the div width of a subgrid and then it started working. Thanks for your reply. Also, please look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304784/limit-adding-search-options-in-jqgrid